# adding a auto increment field to JSONfield in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have been able to insert data into my field which is  JSONField through

```
  modelName.family_member.append({"name":'Brian King',
                    "relationship":'Father',
                    "occupation":'Engineer'})
```

But I wish to add an id field which would auto increase like it does in mysql so data call would be like

```
{'id':1,
"name":'Brian King',
"relationship":'Father',
"occupation":'Engineer'},
{'id':2,
"name":'Demi King',
"relationship":'Mother',
"occupation":'Teacher'},
```

I am using Django and mysql as my database. My model declaration is like this.

```
family_member = models.JSONField(default=jsonfield_default_value)
```

Please how can I get this done

Comment: This is one of the many reasons not to use a JSON field. If the data is structured, one usually uses another model with a `ForeignKey` to the "parent" model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem There are time when creating a new table would not be needed because the field is not that much

Comment: even if it is not that much... You are working with MySQL. This is a *relational* database. While the previous years, they have put effort in making JSON blobs more effective, it is still not very good. It does not allow to efficiently look into the blob, aggregate over the blob, update the blob, etc.

Comment: MongoDB is a database that has JSON as basic format, and has a lot of tooling to make it efficient. That is not the case for (most) relational databases, where it is still good practice to make a new model, since it also comes with integrity checks, etc.

Comment: Adding to that I don't see why the _id_ also needs to be in the JSON? Even if you personally don't specify a PK field Django is going to add one, so you essentially end up with 2 unique values for each record if you do this, adding to unnecessary confusion...

Answer (score 2):

Please *don't* use a `JSONField`. *Relational* databases still can not work very effectively with JSON data. It will for example prevent to efficiently update: what you here do is each time send the entire JSON blob back to the database. As the JSON grows larger, so will the amount of work by the database to update a row. Filtering, updating, removing, etc. are all quite problematic. While there has been put a lot of effort in making working with JSON more convenient, this still is quite "*orthogonal*" on what a *relational* database is supposed to do.

Usually one creates an extra model, so:

```
class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        related_name=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

with `Person` here the model where you defined the relation originally.

You can then add data for example with:

```
FamilyMember.objects.create(
    person=my_person,
    name='Brian King',
    relationship='Father',
    occupation='Engineer'
)
```